# How to find the same ROI for the same text with different colors?

Tags: python, opencv, roi

I am trying to find ROIs on these two images:

[image]

[image]

I'm using this code for image #1:

```py
image_1 = image1
corr1 = []
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1,1), 1)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,10)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
ROI_numbers1 = 0
ROI1 = []
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 5:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image_1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 1)
        ROI1.append(image_1[y:y+h, x:x+w])
        corr1.append([y,y+h, x,x+w])
        ROI_numbers1 += 1
```

And this code for image #2:

```py
image_2 = image2
corr2 = []
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (1,1), 1)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,10)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
ROI_numbers2 = 0
ROI2 = []
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 5:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image_2, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0,255,0), 1)
        ROI2.append(image_2[y:y+h, x:x+w])
        corr2.append([y,y+h, x,x+w])
        ROI_numbers2 += 1
```

After using OpenCV for displaying the ROIs, I am getting this:

[image]

Why is the ROI area for the blue text in image #1 less than for the white text in image #2?

Comment: @HansHirse can you suggest some solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When converting your image(s) to grayscale, you'll get different gray values for the white and blue texts. Thus, `cv2.GaussianBlur` will give different results, and following `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`, too. In the end, the found contours are different, following the ROIs.

Don't convert to grayscale here! In your original, three-channel image, mask anything that's not the background, which is a solid gray `(53, 53, 53)`. That mask replaces your `thresh`. From there, you can then use your existing implementation.

Here's a minimal example to check, whether the resulting bounding rectangles (ROIs) are the same:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


def cnts_from_image(image):
    thresh = (~np.all(image == (53, 53, 53), axis=2)).astype(np.uint8) * 255
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
    dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    return cnts


rects_white = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts_from_image(cv2.imread('white_text.png'))]
rects_blue = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts_from_image(cv2.imread('blue_text.png'))]

print('All rectangles identical:', np.all([rw == rb for rw, rb in zip(rects_white, rects_blue)]))
# All rectangles identical: True
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Its working all good for gray background but not for any other. Should I manually enter different values in (53, 53, 53) to check for different background colors?

Comment: @animesh Exactly, you need to adapt this RGB/BGR value according to the background colour.